Make a SwiftData Model Copy With isAutosaveEnabled
This question is pretty straight-forward, I am wondering if anyone has figured out a way to make a clone or copy of a SwiftData model when your context has isAutosaveEnabled turned on.  My understanding is that each property not labeled Transient has a backingData identifier that relates it to its persistent store.  So doing something like this, doesn't work:
@Model final class User {
    @Attribute var firstName: String
    @Attribute var lastName: String
    @Attribute var createdDate: Date
    @Attribute var imageData: Data

    init(firstName: String,
         lastName: String,
         createdDate: Date,
         imageData: Data) {
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.createdDate = createdDate
        self.imageData = imageData
    }
}

// MARK: - NSCOPYING PROTOCOL
// A protocol that objects adopt to provide functional copies of themselves.

extension User: NSCopying {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        User(firstName: firstName,
             lastName: lastName,
             createdDate: Date(),
             imageData: imageData)
    }
}

Doing the following just alters the model you are wanting to copy.

Just create a new instance and insert it into the ModelContext without any NSCopying extension

@JoakimDanielson yeah tried that too (outside the class, but you establish a reference, thus the NSCopying Protocol).  Even tried valueForKey, no luck.

I have no idea what you mean, when I copy a model object I get a new one with a different memory adress and when I examine it in the debugger both the BackingData and NSManagedObject references are different and my @Query picks up this new object.
